# csv import - how to ingeniously check that the name of columns are "correct"?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, csv, replace

I'm trying to model electrical grid from data manually written in csv.
I have as, an example, a column that is supposed to be called `'DEPART 1'`.
I often can find `'Départ 1'`, `'DEP1'`,`'depart 1'`,`' DEPART 1 '` or many other possibilities...

Right know, i'm importing it with :

```
import_net_data = pd.read_excel(path_file, sheet_name=None)
```

I would like to be able to identify the columns that are close to the "official name" (maybe by ignoring spaces, maj ...)

Is there a way to proper way to :

- replace any of thoses incorrect string (whithout giving all of
  possibilites) by the correct one
- Check if there is only one occurence of thoses column name

Comment: What have you tried so far? I’m not sure how easy it would be without at least checking for a set of different possibilities.

Comment: "Many other possibilities...", like... how many more, 2x, 10x more possibilities?

Comment: And this seems like an _A posteriori_ problem... If you hadn't told me the "official name", how would I as a human (infinitely smarter than a computer) _reason_ that those 4 examples should all equate to `DEPART 1`? How did you arrive at the "official name": your own reasoning, statistical inference, some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you using regular expressions to identify a pattern suitable between these column names, and them replace them with the official name.

You can use the [`re` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to do so. Combine it with [regex101 website](https://regex101.com/) to find the best regular expression to fit for all cases.

Here is a small code sample to solve this particular case:

```py
import re

official_name = "depart 1"

column_names = [
    "Départ 1",
    "DEP1",
    "depart 1",
    " DEPART 1 ",
    " depart      1"]
    
regex = "\s*[d^D][e^E^é^É][p^P]\D*\s*1\s*"

for name in column_names:
    print(name)
    result = re.search(regex, name)
    if result:
        print("Replace with {0}".format(official_name))
    else:
        print("Could not find the regex pattern")
```

It outputs this:

```sh
Départ 1
Replace with depart 1
DEP1
Replace with depart 1
depart 1
Replace with depart 1
 DEPART 1 
Replace with depart 1
 depart      1
Replace with depart 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use **fuzzy string matching** here. For python, as an option, you can look at the [thefuzz](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz) package it's calculate [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for strings.

As an example:

```py
from thefuzz import fuzz


st = 'DEPART 1'
strs = [ 'Départ 1', 'DEP1','depart 1',' DEPART 1 ']

for s in strs:
    l_d= fuzz.ratio(st.lower(), s.lower()) # Levenshtein distance
    print(st, s, '|', 'Levenshtein distance: ', l_d, 'is the same: ', l_d > 60)
```

Output:

```
DEPART 1 Départ 1 | Levenshtein distance:  88   is the same:  True
DEPART 1 DEP1     | Levenshtein distance:  67   is the same:  True
DEPART 1 depart 1 | Levenshtein distance:  100  is the same:  True
DEPART 1 DEPART 1 | Levenshtein distance:  89   is the same:  True
```

Check more info: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python

Using it you can achieve your goals.

**"replace any of thoses incorrect string"**:

```py
import pandas as pd
from thefuzz import fuzz

st = 'DEPART 1'

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['DEPART 1','DEP1','depart 1','depart 1','not even close'])
print(df)

cols = []
for column in df.columns:
    if fuzz.ratio(st.lower(), column.lower()) > 60:
        cols.append(st)
    else:
        cols.append(column)

df.columns = cols

print(df)
```

Output:

```
Columns: [DEPART 1, DEP1, depart 1, depart 1, not even close]
Columns: [DEPART 1, DEPART 1, DEPART 1, DEPART 1, not even close]
```

**"check occurences of column names"**:

```py
import pandas as pd
import collections

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['DEPART 1','DEP1','depart 1','depart 1','not even close'])

print(collections.Counter(df.columns))
```

Output:

```
Counter({'depart 1': 2, 'DEPART 1': 1, 'DEP1': 1, 'not even close': 1})
```